# Where can I buy a PCIe card to add USB 3.0+ ports to my Supermicro SYS-6018U-TR4+?

Tags: usb, server, usb-c

Where can I buy a PCIe card to add USB 3.0+ ports to my Supermicro SYS-6018U-TR4+?

It must:

- physically fit into the server
- be compatible with Linux, at USB 3.0+ speeds

And preferably:

- provide a mix of USB-A and USB-C ports

Comment: You need to fix your question to ask for a **PCIe** card. PCI is a different port and your motherboard doesn't even have one of those! Also, pretty much every card will not fit in a 1U server unless you have a riser to install it horizontally. Do you have that riser?

Comment: @Romen Thanks for your interest, I have submitted a correction to the question PCI -> PCIe. This has been solved; I have located and purchased a card. Indeed my server was equipped with a riser.